# PHP AMQ library encrypted credentials over WAN

Tags: php, ssl, rabbitmq, amqp

I'm working on a project where we have jobs submitted via a web interface (backend is PHP), and those are to appear in a queue (rabbitmq backend) on a server across the WAN.  I have the PHP producer working fine, without any kind of authentication or encryption.

I'm currently working on implementing some kind of authentication (we don't want anyone submitting jobs to our server all willy nilly).

However, I can't find a way in *any* of the PHP libraries to use SSL [I partially have it working on the server, but can't get the client].  I want to avoid someone being able to traffic sniff and get our credentials, and possibly submit jobs.

The jobs being passed are just IDs that relate to a database, so they're not sensitive, just the credentials are.

Is there something I'm missing?  Is there an undocumented feature in any of these libraries?  Is there one I may have not tried?  The one I tried, and currently am using, is the one via PECL (php-amqp I believe).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After even more continuous research, I found another (newer) library, that may be of help.

https://github.com/BraveSirRobin/amqphp

I would still love other input, from others more experienced with AMQ and PHP

Comment: I only 'accepted' my own answer so the question appears as closed now